# mysqldump a table with ignoring a column

Tags: mysql

For example, if I have a table table1 with columns column1, column2, column3.
Is there any way to create mysqldump of the table which will not contain column3?

Or maybe this can be done using different methods (not mysqldump).

Here is what I need to do: sync database1.table1 and database2.table1 (copy table1 to database2) without touching column3 in database2.table1.

Comment: You will not result in _merging_ with skipping 1 column since your export will produce inserts while, it seems, you need updates.